# Wrap all '•' elements with span tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to wrap all bullets in a div with a span tag. The • HTML code is `&#8226;` .

I found the following code that will do this, except it is also stripping out all the links and other HTML code in the div.

```
var $bc = $('#site-nav');
$bc.html($bc.text().split('•').join('<span>•</span>'));
```

How do I wrap all the bullets without losing the links? Here is a fiddle of the above code:

http://jsfiddle.net/76Wvu/6/

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you schould replace `text()` by `html()`

```
var $bc = $('#site-nav');   
$bc.html($bc.html().split('•').join('<span>•</span>'));
```

otherwise u only read the text content of the element, which does not contain any `<a>` tags. Therefore the style and the links are removed.

Comment: YES. Of course it was a simple mistake like that. Thank you! I will mark as the correct answer as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid replacing html and potentially messing with events and data, I would use `wrap()` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/RDf5m/

```
$('#site-nav').contents().filter(function() { 
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text()) == '•';
}).wrap('<span/>');
```